# How to create a comparison page

Tags: php, wordpress, comparison

I want to create a comparison page like [this one](http://fannat.com/compare.aspx) or [this one](http://www.carphonewarehouse.com/mobiles/upgrade/deal-finder) (another way with checkboxes).

I want to make a comparison between the WordPress posts, custom post and the custom fields.

Example: I have a post titled "hello world"

I want to compare this post with the other posts in a special compared page in a table.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's a bit too broad question, depends of what you want to achieve in the end you may want to use filters from a commerce plugin like Woocommerce.

Though if you want to do this by hand, you should first add your filter data in data attribute for your posts to get something like this:

```
<div class="my-item" data-title="title of the post"
                     data-meta-field-1="value of meta field 1"
                     data-meta-field-12="value of meta field 2"
                     data-post-type="post type">
```

Then do you filter form (checkboxes or whatever you want) and listen change on it with jQuery, and hide / show the posts depends of the form selection and their data attributes.